# How to predict the outcome of a new patient using this SVC ML model trained on a dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Data description:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

np.random.seed(0)

# Alternatively X and y can be obtained directly from the frame attribute:
X = df.drop('OUTCOME', axis=1)
y = df['OUTCOME']

numeric_features = ['Age', 'PCT' , 'CURB 65' , 'pO2' ]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_features = ['Sex', 'CXR' , 'Hospitalisation in last 3 months' , 'ICU>72hrs', 'Blood']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])
from sklearn import linear_model

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', SVC())])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Accuracy of the model is 1.0
How to enter new patient's parameter to get a prediction for that patient? New patient is not from this dataset.

i tried to enter new patient information as follows

```
New_patient = [70,1,0,2,2,10,40,2,20,68,1,2,0,1,1]
clf.predict([New_patient])
```

output: ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some more information on what you've tried already and why it didn't work.

Comment: thanks.i did edit the problem though. i am able to get model running on test data but how to enter a data for a new patient for which the model can presdict the outcome.